# Retornar registro apenas de apostas mais recentes que a hora atual

Tags: mongodb

queria retornar esse registro apenas se todos os `apostas.horario` fosse maior que a hora atual, como posso fazer isso em mongodb?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode adicionar esse trecho ai em forma de texto?

Comment: de uma lida nesse post que vai te dar uma luz  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: beleza amigo obrigado